# jQuery UI Sortable/Draggable/Droppable combo – index of dropped Draggable in Sortable+Draggable list N/A

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a sectioned/nested list; each section contains an `ul.items` which is both Sortable and Droppable. The sections themselves are Sortable, but not Droppable. Each `ul.items` connects with other sections’ `ul.items`, enabling the moving of items between sections.

```
<div class="section">  <!-- Sortable -->
    <ul class="items"> <!-- Sortable, Droppable -->
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="section">  <!-- Sortable -->
    <ul class="items"> <!-- Sortable, Droppable -->
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On my page, I also have a search box. Search results are rendered out as a list, and each list item made Draggable. I match the scope of the Draggables with that of the Droppables, and I’m able to drop the search results into any `ul.items`.

```
<ul class="search-results">
    <li>Stuff</li> <!-- Draggable -->
    <li>Stuff</li> <!-- Draggable -->
</ul>
```

My problem, however, is that jQuery UI doesn’t provide me with enough information about the context where the Draggable was dropped. I’ve tried both Sortable’s `receive` event and Droppable’s `drop` event, with no luck.

I guess I can get the Draggable’s new index in the Droppable list somehow, searching through the Droppable comparing each item to `ui.draggable`/`ui.sender`, but it seems like a lot of work for something that seems like a common enough use case.

Alternatively, I could make the search results list Sortable and connect it with each `ul.items`, just as I connect them with each other, but the thing is, **I really don’t want the search results to be Sortable**.

Any input much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried sortable's stop event? i am not sure, but i hope it might help u   http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop

Comment: Well, the arguments provided to the stop callback are the same as the ones provided to the update function, so there shouldn’t really be any difference. `ui.placeholder` kind of looks like what I need, but I didn’t have any luck there, either.

Comment: I just googled this even more, and found this; http://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-item-that-was-dropped-into-a-sortable – the poorly documented `$(this).data('ui-sortable').element` might just be what I need. Will test this sometime and report back here.